# Using DOMXpath to catch all team names from a page in PHP

Tags: php, domxpath

I'm would like to extract all the team name and link from this page:

```
https://www.transfermarkt.fr/ligue-1/startseite/wettbewerb/FR1
```

I'm using [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to match element but with the following code it do not return me anything.

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.fr/ligue-1/startseite/wettbewerb/FR1';
$html = get_data($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "hide-for-pad", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "tooltipstered", " " ))]') as $v) {
    echo $v->getAttribute("href") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Do you know why please ?

Thanks a any help.

Comment: $html = get_data($url); Can you add the HTML response in code?

Comment: @ShivendraSingh, the `$html` is the one from `https://www.transfermarkt.fr/ligue-1/startseite/wettbewerb/FR1` url.

Comment: @ShivendraSingh, the response is too big. It contains a lot of lines.

Comment: Oh Okay. I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the HTML is altered by Javascript once the page is loaded.  I've had a look at the page and I think you should be able to get the details from the following (please check the correct URL is displayed)...

```
$teams = $xpath->query('//td[@class="zentriert no-border-rechts"]/a[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "vereinprofil_tooltip", " " ))]');
foreach($teams as $v) {
    echo $v->getAttribute("href") . " - ";
    echo $v->firstChild->getAttribute("alt").PHP_EOL;
}
```

This may give duplicates, so a possibility is to create a list of the teams and URL's like this...

```
$teams = [];
foreach($teams as $v) {
    $teams[$v->firstChild->getAttribute("alt")] = $v->getAttribute("href");
}
```

Which will give you a list of team names (as the key) and the URL as the value.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Could you please explain me more why your query is working and mine not? Also, with your actual code I get 40 teams and not 20.

Comment: Rather than looking at the HTML through a browser, I will always save the HTML retrieved and look through that for markers (such as the classes for the various elements).  I looked for the string `tooltipstered` in the HTML and I can't find it anywhere, so there is obviously something going on there.  In my code I've found something which looks as though it matches.  There is a problem in that if the server code is changed, then this may fail at any point.

Comment: Last question: why this query can't work? `//td[@class="zentriert no-border-rechts"]/a[@class="vereinprofil_tooltip tooltipstered"]` ?

Comment: If you look at the source code of the HTML (at least the bit I'm looking at) only has `<a class="vereinprofil_tooltip" href="/fc-p` - so is doesn't have the `tooltipstered` class.